# preference screen doesn't honor NoTitleBar theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

My preference activity has a preference category that contains multiple preference screens.  The screens are added dynamically at run-time.  I build each in code and add it to the preference group.  The screens don't actually set preferences on the device; instead, they make calls to a server to set them there.  This is done by setting them all persistent = false and configuring a preference change listener on each.

My problem is this:  My app doesn't use title bars.  I've disabled them by setting a theme of "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in my manifest, but the view created by each preference screen in my preference activity have a title bar nevertheless.  Its text is set to the title of the preference screen.

I can't just not set a title, because then it's absent when the preference activity is displayed.

I tried setting a layout resource on the PreferenceScreen in code and having that resource use the NoTitleBar theme, but when the screen's view is inflated it seems to ignore all the titles, summaries, etc. that I set in code (as opposed to in the referenced layout).

I also tried setting the NoTitleBar theme on the layout for the preference activity, as well as the preference category.  No effect.

I even considered sub-classing PreferenceScreen and overriding getView() to set all my dynamic info on the view before it's returned but PreferenceScreen is declared final.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Its Strange!!

Put `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in PreferenceActivity

Comment: That removes the title bar on the PreferenceActivity itself, but not on the individual PreferenceScreens that are part of that Activity.